# 64 bit side-loaded app to use Brokered Windows Runtime Components

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, ipc, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit (x86) side-loaded `Windows Store app` that works with a brokered Windows Runtime Component, it works smoothly and can launch desktop exe, load desktop dll using Reflection, etc.

I want to make this side-loaded app 64-bit. And after rebuilding the app as x64, it can never use the brokered Windows Runtime Component again. The error is

> Additional information:
>
> Unable to cast COM object of type 'StoreAppBrokeredWindowsRuntimeComponent.DirectInvoker' to interface type 'StoreAppBrokeredWindowsRuntimeComponent.IDirectInvokerClass'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{50EA3FD3-2383-5445-4002-8CBCBED5DB0F}' failed due to the following error: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

From the doc [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for a side-loaded Windows Store app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps),

> Side-loaded applications can be 64-bit (provided there is both a 64-bit and 32-bit proxies registered), but this will be atypical.

**Question:**

How to build a 64-bit proxy?

The [VS template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-713547.BrokeredWinRTComponentProjectTemplates) can only build 32 bit (Win32) proxy. If change the `WindowsRuntimeProxyStub` to x64, it cannot even be compiled - there are a bunch of LINK errors.

[image]

So 32-bit side-loaded app, 32-bit brokered Windows runtime component, and 32-bit proxy is the *only* working approach so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Microsoft Support, I have successfully built a 64 bit brokered runtime component and used it from a 64-bit side-loaded app.

To make it easier to follow, just use the following MS sample projects. You don't need to modify *any* code file at all.  However, there are two errors in the template you need to fix first, see ***Important Notes*** at the end of this answer.

[Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps - Server](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Brokered-Windows-Runtime-9d64cada)

[Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps - Client](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Brokered-Windows-Runtime-74899ea2)

## *Steps to build 64-bit brokered component and proxy*

1. Unzip the code package(Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps - Server.zip) and open the solution with Visual studio 2013 (**Run as Administrator**);
2. Change the platform of `SampleProxy` project from Win32 to x64;
3. Open `SampleProxy Property`->`Configuration Properties`->`Preprocessor`->`Preprocessor Definitions`, and change two of definitions

> WIN32->X64; REGISTER_PROXY_DLLWIN32->REGISTER_PROXY_DLL

4. Change the platform of `EnterpriseIPCServer` project to x64.
5. Edit Post-build event command line of `EnterpriseIPCServer`, replace each occurrence of `x86` or `Win32` with `x64`, the command should be like this:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64

md "$(TargetDir)"\impl
md "$(TargetDir)"\reference

erase "$(TargetDir)\impl\*.winmd"
erase "$(TargetDir)\impl\*.pdb"
rem erase "$(TargetDir)\reference\*.winmd"

xcopy /y "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)impl"
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.pdb" "$(TargetDir)impl"

winmdidl /nosystemdeclares /metadata_dir:C:\Windows\System32\Winmetadata "$(TargetPath)"

midl /metadata_dir "%WindowsSdkDir%References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" /iid "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName)_i.c" /env x64 /x64 /h "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName).h" /winmd "$(TargetName).winmd" /W1 /char signed /nologo /winrt /dlldata "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\dlldata.c" /proxy "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName)_p.c"  "$(TargetName).idl"

mdmerge -n 1 -i "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)" -o "$(TargetDir)reference" -metadata_dir "%WindowsSdkDir%References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" -partial

rem erase "$(TargetPath)"
```

6. First build the `EnterpriseIPCServer` project.
7. Then build the `SampleProxy` project.

Check the output files (Fabrikam.winmd & SampleProxy.dll).

## *Steps to use the 64-bit brokered component and proxy*

Tricky enough, the 64-bit brokered runtime component is never used at all. All we need is the 32-bit brokered runtime component, but we need to register **both** 32-bit and 64-bit proxy.

Put the 3 files (32-bit brokered runtime component + 2 proxies) under the same folder, for example, C:\test. Then execute the following commands.

> regsvr32.exe C:\test\SampleProxy_64.dll (I have renamed the 64-bit proxy)
>
> regsvr32.exe C:\test\SampleProxy.dll  (this is the 32 bit proxy)
>
> icacls C:\test /T /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":RX

Then in the 64-bit side-load app, reference the 32-bit brokered runtime component. But be careful to pick the one in the "reference" folder, don't reference the one in the "impl" folder.

For your reference, I have uploaded the code to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kennyzx/Broker_x64).

## *Important Notes*

There are some errors in this sample project, which make it a nightmare to build it for the x86/win32 configuration.

In the x86 configuration of  **EnterpriseIPCServer**, the following command in the post build event contains an unrecognizable switch **/x86**, it should be **/win32**.

> midl /metadata_dir "%25WindowsSdkDir%25References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" /iid "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName)_i.c" /env win32 /x86 /h "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName).h" /winmd "$(TargetName).winmd" /W1 /char signed /nologo /winrt /dlldata "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\dlldata.c" /proxy "$(SolutionDir)SampleProxy\$(TargetName)_p.c"  "$(TargetName).idl"

In the **Win32** configuration of the **SampleProxy** project, one of the preprocessor definitions **REGISTER_PROXY_DLLWIN32** should be **REGISTER_PROXY_DLL**.